# How to upload/embed a MP3 file into expression engine?

Tags: templates

Good afternoon.  I am new to EE, and am trying to upload an MP3 audio file to our webpage.  I am able to upload pics, PDF, etc..., but for some reason cannot figure out what to do for an MP3.  Can someone help?

Comment: We're going to need more details, like what EE version are you running; have you checked the file upload settings for the folder you're trying to upload too?...

Answer (score 0):

you'll most likely need to choose to allow all file types in your file directory upload permission settings and you may also need to look into adding the MIME type for MP3 to your server. You can also disable XSS filtering to allow file type checking to be bypassed, but it is better to set the correct MIME type and keep XSS on if possible.